# SQL Server display 2 rows of data as 1 row

Tags: sql, sql-server

In a SQL Server query, I'm trying to figure out how to combine two rows of data into one row for specific records.

The following is an example of table data. Below it is how I would like the data to be displayed. I want to display all available columns for each employee but on 1 row. I tried group by but that did not work as I want all the columns displayed.

I'd like to display only one row for certain employees who have two rows. I can use EMP ID because it is associated with a specific employee. Any suggestions for the best way to accomplish this in SQL Server?

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Whybdo a Brad have an end date of the 26th, but everyone else gets 27th?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question lacks some information, but overall it sounds like this is what you need:

```
SELECT t.dept_name, t.team_name, t.employee_name, t.emp_id,
       max(t.count1) as count1, max(t.count2) as count2, max(t.count3) as count3,
       max(t.start_dt) as start_dt, max(t.end_dt) as end_dt, 
       max(t.load_date) as load_date
FROM YourTable t
GROUP BY t.dept_name, t.team_name, t.employee_name, t.emp_id
```

I assumed `t.dept_name, t.team_name, t.employee_name, t.emp_id` is the way you want to group them, and that only one of the two records will hold a value for the counts (if not you need to decide which one you want). Also the dates weren't clear, because for `dept a` you chose the first one and for the rest you chose the second one, so I used `max`.

Comment: Thanks sagi, this is exactly what i needed, appreciate the help!